# Java generic compareTo

Tags: java, generics, compareto

I have developed/implemented a generic `compareTo` method in Java. So that for any object you define, it will hava a `compareTo` method. Is this relevant? Please answer and comment.

Comment: "relevant" to what?

Comment: Leave the superior/inferior aside. You can not say that 3 is superior to 1. You just say that is at a distance of 2. So the compareTo is showing how different is an object from other object of the same type.

Comment: "Leave the superior/inferior aside" => But that's the nature of the `compareTo` method! Quote from [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html): "This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's _natural ordering_, and the class's compareTo method is referred to as its _natural comparison method_."

Comment: Let's say you intend to compare a bottle of Coca-Cola with a bottle Schweppes(instances of Beverage let's say). And we presume that compareTo will return 3. If you compare a bottle of Schweppes with a bottle of Coca-Cola the result will be -3. And finally, if you compare a bottle of Schweppes with a bottle of Schweppes the result of compareTo will be 0. practically you determine the distance in spatiality.

Comment: @Aaron, basically the `compareTo` method is really for homogeneous sets

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez right, my initial reasoning was flawed since `comparesTo` applies to members of a same class anyway. Seelenvirtuose's point is relevant though : you can't have a generic compareTo because not all classes represent sets of objects with total order. [You can't order complex numbers for instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers).

Comment: Leave total order aside

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for SO to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: There is already a library that does that: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

Answer (score 3):

Go to [this site](https://www.jcp.org/en/home/index) in order to submit proposals. Read the **Welcome to the Java Community Process!**:

> ..... Anyone can register for the site and participate in reviewing
>   and providing feedback for the Java Specification Requests (JSRs), and
>   anyone can sign up to become a JCP Member and then participate on the
>   Expert Group of a JSR or even submit their own JSR Proposals.

Also in the [How to Contribute](http://openjdk.java.net/contribute/) section OpenJDK site, they mention these steps:

1. Become a Contributor
2. Find something interesting to work on
3. Discuss your intended change
4. Submit a patch
5. Work with your [sponsor](http://openjdk.java.net/sponsor/)
6. Know what to expect

Good luck with that. And please share it with us too

Comment: Ok, but I would like some form of acknowledgement, like a Nobel Prize

Comment: Start by being a [Java champion](https://community.oracle.com/community/java/java-champions). You have to crawl before walking